# How to watch a parent controller variable changed by a child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to save user.preferences everytime they change, so, user.preferences is an App variable.

HTML

```
      ...
      ng-controller="AppController as App"
      ...
```

On app.js

```
    vm.preferences = localStorage.preferences === undefined ?  initialPreferences : JSON.parse(localStorage.preferences) ;

    $scope.$watch('App.preferences',function() {

        localStorage.preferences = JSON.stringify(vm.preferences);

    });
```

The child controller CAN change the variable  but the watcher doesn't trigger. Any clue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googled a little more, if you wan't to watch an entire Object you must specify the third argument of `$watch`: objectEquality.

From AngularJS Docs:

> Compare for object equality using angular.equals instead of comparing for reference equality.

Watching an entire object:

```
$scope.$watch('App.preferences',function() {

    localStorage.preferences = JSON.stringify(vm.preferences);

},true);
```